# Android sync of files and database using Dropbox

Tags: android, database, file, synchronization, dropbox

I am looking for a way to sync database and photos between devices trough Dropbox. The purpose is that **several devices** can add delete and update data and photos.

I thought about exporting the .db file but it would be difficult to update, I think it would rather overwrite the previous file. Maybe working with CSV is a good approach, because the app would be actually read and compare before updating its database and files.

The app will have something likea sync button or something that trigger sync.

I know that it would be correct to use an own SQL server, but I would rather avoid that.

Any ideas?

Comment: i know that this is an old question, but i just wrote an answer that i think that is related to this one, about how to sync apps.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21299528/2357411