# Share single google map among multiple device

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Say I have an app that uses google map , and I'm the controller , I can add markers , remove markers , etc... the question is how can I let some one else on another device to see my map 
in dynamic fashion i.e. if I deleted/added a marker and he refreshed , he will see the changes happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sync the two apps, using for instance a database in a webserver where all the apps sends and read the updates in their statuts. For that you have to make calls to a php server, sending and receiving the info probably in json.

Also, you can try to use [sync adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

> Synchronizing data between an Android device and web servers can make
>   your application significantly more useful and compelling for your
>   users. For example, transferring data to a web server makes a useful
>   backup, and transferring data from a server makes it available to the
>   user even when the device is offline. In some cases, users may find it
>   easier to enter and edit their data in a web interface and then have
>   that data available on their device, or they may want to collect data
>   over time and then upload it to a central storage area.
>
> Although you can design your own system for doing data transfers in
>   your app, you should consider using Android's sync adapter framework.
>   This framework helps manage and automate data transfers, and
>   coordinates synchronization operations across different apps. When you
>   use this framework, you can take advantage of several features that
>   aren't available to data transfer schemes you design yourself:

in the given link you can find more information, and also an example app

Comment: hmmm I don't really like the database idea , because it's  only one map that get read by users , I guess the appropriate question would be what format/way should I store the map on the server? like should I update it and save it as static map or maybe save the markers or something ?

Comment: it is easy: you save some parameters, like the coordinates of the center of the map, and the zoom level. in another table, you save the coordinates of every marker, the name and the description if you want. with that you can easily replicate the map

Comment: yes that's the intuitive way, but this means , if I had 1000 marker , and then I added new marker , client will need to "redraw" the 1001 marker not the new 1 , so any other descent method ?

Comment: if you dont like to use a database, you can use a text file or json file with that data. it will be just a file and really simple

Comment: you dont need to redraw all, if you keep track of the time the marker was added, or the number of markers (the client ask for the marker starting in the numer n), or create an id to every of them

Comment: I would do it width the id, so somebody can check for updates, and the way to go will be looking at what new ids there are, and if some of the old ids has to be deleted

Comment: to be honest until now I don't have the answer I want ,because I will be drawing all the marks upon client query what I want is something like this http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_store.htm

Comment: the example is great! but it is more or less what we are talking about. it sends the coordinates to the server when the user press submit, and then in the next request it prints all the markers (but there is not auto sync between clients), so it is easier, since in the request you just retrieve all the markers from the database and create the map